# Execute JS using Python and store results in an array

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I am working on this [website](https://www.ifrs.org/use-around-the-world/use-of-ifrs-standards-by-jurisdiction/) where there is an SVG map and radio buttons as filters :

[image]

To get the result of the filter in the map (countries colored in blue), I execute this javascript snippet :

```
var n = $("input[name=adoptionStatus]:checked").val();
    (n == undefined || n === "") && (n = "00000000000000000000000000000000");
    $(".status-text").hide();
    $("#" + n).show();
    $("#vmap").vectorMap("set", "colors", resetColorsData);
    resetColorsData = {};
    colorsData = {};
    $("#countries_list a").each(function(t, i) {
        $(i).data("adoption-status").indexOf(n) >= 0 && (colorsData[$(i).data("country-code")] = "#2f98cb", resetColorsData[$(i).data("country-codecountry-code")] = "#fefefe")
    });
    $("#vmap").vectorMap("set", "colors", colorsData)
```

The variable `n` is used to store the value of the radio button like in this case `cae64c6b731d47cca7565b2a74d11d53` :

```
<div class="map-filter-radio radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="adoptionStatus" alt="IFRS Standards are permitted, but not required, for use by at least some domestic publicly accountable entities, including listed companies and financial institutions." title="IFRS Standards are permitted, but not required, for use by at least some domestic publicly accountable entities, including listed companies and financial institutions." value="cae64c6b731d47cca7565b2a74d11d53">
                IFRS Standards are permitted but not required for domestic public companies
            </label>
</div>
```

When I execute the Javascript in the console and try to get the `colorsData`, I get the list of the countries colored in blue like below :

```
bm: "#2f98cb"
ch: "#2f98cb"
gt: "#2f98cb"
iq: "#2f98cb"
jp: "#2f98cb"
ky: "#2f98cb"
mg: "#2f98cb"
ni: "#2f98cb"
pa: "#2f98cb"
py: "#2f98cb"
sr: "#2f98cb"
tl: "#2f98cb"
```

[image]

How can I execute the JS script on the webpage and get the result of the colored countries in an array using `python` ?

Comment: Is there a reason for why you don't use a more readable `if ( ... ) { ... }` instead of those (imho terrible) `... && ... ` / `... && ... , ...` one-liners?

Comment: @Andreas  I got the script from the website. It's not my work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the list of countries specified by `#countries_list`, you got a list of `a` tag like the following :

```
<a id="country_bd" data-country-code="bd" data-adoption-status="97f9b22998d546f7856bb1b4f0586521|3adc18f07ff64c908a6d835e08344531|ff784361818644798ea899f81b8b6d61" href="/use-around-the-world/use-of-ifrs-standards-by-jurisdiction/bangladesh/">
    <img src="/-/media/7bfd06a698594c2cb3614578a41caa9e.ashx" alt="Bangladesh">
    Bangladesh
</a>
```

The `data-adoption-status` attribute is a list of `adoptionStatus` delimited by `|`.

You just need to split them and match only the countries that reference the value from the `input` adoptionValue like this :

```
if selectedAdoptionStatus in t["data-adoption-status"].split("|")
```

The following code lists all `input` tag and extracts the `adoptionStatus` for each one of these, it prompts user to choose a filter (0 to 4) and gets the selected countries by filtering on the `data-adoption-status` attribute :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.ifrs.org/use-around-the-world/use-of-ifrs-standards-by-jurisdiction/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

choiceContainer = soup.find("div", {"class":"map-filters"})

choices = [
    (t["title"], t["value"])
    for t in choiceContainer.findAll("input")
]

for idx, choice in enumerate(choices):
    print(f"[{idx}] {choice[0]}")
val = input("Choose a filter index : ") 
choice = choices[int(val)]

print(f"You have chosen {choice[0]}")

selectedAdoptionStatus = choice[1]

countryList = soup.find("div", {"id":"countries_list"})
selectedCountries = [
    {
        "countryCode": t["data-country-code"],
        "adoptionStatus": t["data-adoption-status"].split("|"),
        "link": t["href"],
        "country": t.find("img")["alt"]
    }
    for t in countryList.findAll("a")
    if selectedAdoptionStatus in t["data-adoption-status"].split("|")
]

for it in selectedCountries:
    print(it["country"])
```

[run this code on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeCountriesAdoptionStatus)

---

Sample output

```
[0] IFRS Standards are required for use by all or most domestic publicly accountable entities.
[1] IFRS Standards are permitted, but not required, for use by at least some domestic publicly accountable entities, including listed companies and financial institutions.
[2] IFRS Standards are required or permitted for use by foreign securities issuers.
[3] In most cases an SME may also choose full IFRS Standards. In some cases, an SME may also choose local standards for SMEs.
[4] The body with authority to adopt financial reporting standards is actively studying whether to adopt the <em>IFRS for SMEs</em> Standard.
Choose a filter index : 1
You have chosen IFRS Standards are permitted, but not required, for use by at least some domestic publicly accountable entities, including listed companies and financial institutions.
Bermuda
Cayman Islands
Guatemala
Iraq
Japan
Madagascar
Nicaragua
Panama
Paraguay
Suriname
Switzerland
Timor-Leste
```